# Go bug in ioutil.ReadFile()

Tags: go

I am running a program in Go which sends data continuously after reading a file `/proc/stat`.
Using `ioutil.ReadFile("/proc/stat")`
After running for about 14 hrs i got err: `too many files open /proc/stat`
Click [here](http://play.golang.org/p/iiqLOhEgHv) for snippet of code.

I doubt that defer `f.Close` is ignored by Go sometimes or it is skipping it.

---

The snippet of code (in case play.golang.org dies sooner than stackoverflow.com):

```
package main

import ("fmt";"io/ioutil")

func main() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
        fData,err := ioutil.ReadFile("/proc/stat")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Err is ",err)
        }   
        fmt.Println("FileData",string(fData))
    }
}
```

Comment: [First Rule of Programming: It's always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: first rule of stackoverflow: post the faulty code, not some after-production that doesn't certainly reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm curious, did you ever find out what it was?

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, but there is way to close the file as it is only `ReadFile()` no ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason probably is that somewhere in your program:

- you are forgetting to close files, or
- you are leaning on the garbage collector to automatically close files on object finalization, but Go's conservative garbage collector fails to do so. In this case you should check your program's memory consumption (whether it is steadily increasing while the program is running).

In either case, try to check the contents of `/proc/PID/fd` to see whether the number of open files is increasing while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you Do the f.Close(),it still has the proble,Maybe it is because your other connection,for example the connection to MYSQL,also will be cause the problem,especially,in a loop,and you forget to close the connection.

Always do :

```
db.connection....
**defer db.Close()**

If it is in loop

loop
    db.connection....
    **defer db.Close()**
end
```

Do not put the db.connection before the loop